# Failed to add callback to vector

Tags: c++, callback

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I would like to append `Button::track_` function to the `callbacks` vector so that all functions inside `callbacks` will be called once the `invoke_all` function in events class was called.

**buttons.h**

```
class Button:
    public Texture
{
public:
    void track();
}
```

**buttons.cpp**

```
void Button::track()
{
    Events::add_handler(&Button::track_);
}

void Button::track_() { ... }
```

**events.h**

```
typedef std::function<void()> cb;
extern std::vector<cb> callbacks;

class Events
{
public:
    static void add_handler(cb);
    static void invoke_all();
};
```

**events.cpp**

```
std::vector<cb> callbacks;

void Events::add_handler(cb c)
{
    callbacks.push_back(c);
}

void Events::invoke_all()
{
    decltype(callbacks.size()) i = 0;
    for (; i < callbacks.size(); i++)
        callbacks[i]();
}
```

I always get this error message

> Error C2893:  Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'    SDL d:\programs\microsoft visual studio 2015\vc\include\type_traits 1494

Comment: Which line triggers the error? Is it inside `Events::invoke_all`? What is its code? Please, create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a non-static member function pointer without an instance of the class to call it on. I'm guessing you want to capture an instance of `Button` in the `std::function` function object. One way of doing this is using a [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11):

```
void Button::track()
{
    Events::add_handler([this]{track_();});
}
```

By capturing `this` in the lambda you can then implicitly call member functions on that instance within the body of the lambda.

Of course you need to guarantee that the `Button` instance is alive when the callback is called.

Comment: Can you explain what's this thingy `[this]{track_();}` does because I'm only a newbie. I know how to instantiate a class, but in that case it's beyond my experience.

Comment: @Xtravagant It is a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda); sometimes called lambda functions, anonymous functions, closures, or similar.

Comment: Do I still have to do that even if I specify `Button::track()` as static or shared?

Comment: @Xtravagant As I say, if `Button::track()` is static then you don't need an instance of `Button` to call it and you should be able to pass the function pointer directly. I've added a link explaining what a lambda is.